# Determine if a stream is full buffered

Tags: c, linux, unix

I know the `__flbf` function can tell me if a stream is line buffered or not in Linux, but how to determine if a stream is full buffered or not?

Comment: By "full buffered", do you mean "block buffered"? Streams in C can only be unbuffered, block buffered or line buffered. There's no such thing as "full buffered".

Comment: sorry, it's "fully buffered", not "full buffered", it came from <Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use a combination of `__flbf` and `__fbufsize` to see if the file is unbuffered, line buffered or block buffered?

Like

```
if (__flbf(some_file))
    printf("File is line buffered\n");
else if (__fbufsize(some_file) == 0)
    printf("File is unbuffered\n");
else
    printf("File is block (aka fully) buffered\n");
```

Comment: thanks, now I figure out. And sorry for tolerate my poor english.